# Get the value of a textfield into a cell of table using javascript

Tags: javascript

How can i get the value of a textfield which is into a cell of a table using javascript?

This is my piece of code:

```
<table id="elenco2" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2" class="sortable" style="width:98%;">
    <tbody>
        <tr> 
            <th align='left'>Informazione</th>
            <th align='left'>Valore</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <ctl:input name="idtbin" tipo="text" flIns="H" flMod="H" flVis="H" arrayindex="${indice}" value="<%=valobene.getIdtbin().toString()%>" />
                <ctl:input name="tipo" tipo="text" flIns="H" flMod="H" flVis="H" size="50" maxlength="50" arrayindex="${indice}" value="<%=valobene.getTipo()%>" />
                <ctl:input name="informazione" tipo="text" flIns="L" flMod="L" flVis="L" size="50" maxlength="50" arrayindex="${indice}" value="<%=valobene.getInformazione()%>" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <ctl:input name="valore" tipo="text" flIns="E" flMod="E" flVis="L" size="50" maxlength="50" arrayindex="${indice}" value="<%=valobene.getValore()%>" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: assign id to textfield and get by `document.getElementById('ID');`

Comment: What is `ctl:` from and should this be tagged to this post as well? Otherwise iot is as simple as @PHPExpert says: `document.getElementById('table-cell-id').textValue = document.getElementById('textarea-id')`. (Note that `getElementById` could be replaced by any other selector function)